# Why can't constructors with non-primitive return type be invoked without new?

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function MyAnimation(duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.tick.bind(this));
            return new Promise((resolve)=>{resolve()}); //returning primitive type executes the instance
        }
MyAnimation.prototype.tick = function (time) {
            start_stamp=(!start_stamp)?time:start_stamp;
            elapsed=time-start_stamp;
            range=(elapsed>this.duration)?this.duration:elapsed; 
            test_elem2.style.transform="rotateY("+0.09*range+"deg)";
            return (elapsed<=this.duration)?requestAnimationFrame(this.tick.bind(this)):'done';
        }
const anim_obj=new MyAnimation;
anim_obj.constructor(1000);
```

I know ES6 classes are to be invoked with new but returning a primitive type for the constructor yields no error whereas returning the promise yields:

> Promise constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: To chain another animation with promise

Comment: I think you misunderstand what constructors are for...

Comment: I know constructors can't be recursive, just curious why it executes if I use `return 5;` instead

Comment: From the entire construct it is not clear where the OP assumes the chainability to happen.